# Executable made from pyinstaller is not compatible in windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, pyinstaller

I built a program in Linux using Python and used Pyinstaller to create an executable. When I run the executable on Windows 10, it tells me that the software is not compatible with Windows 10 and won't run.

I tried the compatibility solver/wizard and the program still won't run on Windows 10.

Is there something I might have missed while using Pyinstaller?
Or do I need to install some programs on windows 10 to make it work?

Comment: What command arguments did you use? What is the error you are getting? Is it GUI application?

Comment: Are you running the same version of python across both platforms?

Comment: You need to run `Pyinstaller` on Windows 10 in order to make a Windows 10 executable.

Comment: I use the executable created from pyinstaller on windows. error I get "to find a version for your PC, contact the software publisher"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your program to run on Windows you have to use PyInstaller on Windows to create the executable for Windows.

Comment: but is there a way to make it compatible on both os?

Comment: Yes. You can keep it as python file and if your code is not platform specific then you can run it on both platforms. Linux executable is ELF and Windows PE. They are completely different and you cant run it on other platforms. You could theoretically use wine on linux to run your exe but it doesnt always work.

Comment: The program I have runs on Ubuntu desktop, but it also has trouble running on ubuntu-mate. was it the same problem?